# Set Position Value from Index for nested model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem, acts-as-list

How can I set a position field in the attributes for a nested model so that my has_many relationship remembers it's sort order?

I want to set the position from the index so that it reflects the order the relations have been dragged into.

I have a form with Nested fields, using the cocoon gem with JQuery Sortable allowing each field-set to be drag-sortable.

I want to update the order of all the fields on saving the form.

Comment: What are the names of the two model classes in your relationship?

Comment: @MaxWilliams - resume and education.  resume has_many educations

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "act_as_list" gem.

```
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todo_items, -> { order(position: :asc) }
end

class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :todo_list
  acts_as_list scope: :todo_list
end

todo_list = TodoList.find(...)
todo_list.todo_items.first.move_to_bottom
todo_list.todo_items.last.move_higher
```

Refer: https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

Answer (score 0):

If you have the standard CRUD/restful routes and controller actions set up, then all you are wanting to do is to call "update_attributes(:position => 3)" on an instance of the nested class (education in this case).

The usual route to update an education which is nested under "resume" would be

```
UPDATE  /resumes/123/educations/456
```

so, you'll be making an ajax call to this url.  The "UPDATE" method isn't really an update method, it's sort of spoofed by passing through a parameter `"_method" = "UPDATE"`, so your ajax call will need to include this parameter too.

So, basically, on the "finished dragging" event, you're going to be making an ajax call to this url

```
"/resumes/<%= @resume.id %>/educations/<%= education.id %>"
```

and passing data like

```
{"_method": "UPDATE", "education[position]": <new position>}
```

This should update the position of the education object.

The other remaining issue is that, with acts_as_list, when we change the position of one item, we want the others to adjust their position automatically, too.  I'm not sure if acts_as_list does this automatically.  Try it.

Comment: ah, when you said you were using jquery sortable i assumed you were doing ajax calls whenever the user finished dragging an item.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, non ajaxy version.

Let's assume that your form is a `form_for @resume`, which means that it will call the resumes#create or resumes#update action.

If all the `education` rows in your list have a hidden field like this

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "resume[education_ids][]", education.id %>
```

then when the form is submitted, they will go through into an array in params[:resume][:education_ids] **in the order in which they appear in the page when the form was submitted**, which is what you want.

The association gives you the setter method Resume#education_ids, allowing you to set the associations, in order, this way.

Ie, your update action will (if it's a normal update action) be saying something like

```
@resume = Resume.find_by_id(params[:id])
if @resume.update_attributes(params[:resume])
  ...
```

in this case, this will be saying

```
@resume.update_attributes(:education_ids => [5,6,2,1])
```

which is like saying "set my educations to be those with ids 5,6,2,1, in that order.

CAVEAT: in my version of rails (this might be fixed in subsequent version), if you use this _ids method, and it already has associations, but in a different order, it WILL NOT reorder them.  Give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @MaxWilliams - The form can add and remove education items as well as reorder them.  That's why i need to take the position for each education record from it's position in the params.  It's index.

Comment: So this won't work. I don't know the id's of all the records.  in fact some don't have an id on save because they are new.

Comment: You need to explain this stuff, ie your requirements, in your question. I'm guessing because you don't give any details of what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks max, i appreciate you trying to help me out.  I've added a working, but ugly answer that probably clarifies further.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be the best way to do it, but I have got this working in my controller.

```
p = 1
experiences = []
params[:user][:resume_attributes][:experiences_attributes].each do |e|          
    e = e.last.merge(:position=>p)
    experiences << e
    p = p + 1
end
params[:user][:resume_attributes][:experiences_attributes] = experiences
```

which at least illustrates what i want to achieve.

Comment: Can you copy some example values for `params[:user]` into this answer please, so we can see what's going on here?